# Jquery: How to use this in a ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I think I do not understand the use of "this" in jQuery. If I want something to happen when hover to any element of an ul. How I use this?

The example live here: http://jsfiddle.net/WREjV/

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="first">first</li>
    <li id="second">second</li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu").hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    },function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    /* This works:
    $("#first").click(function() {
        $("#first").fadeOut("slow");
    });
    */
})
```

Comment: Where is your fiddle code? its empty :)

Comment: In your case `$(this)` refers to `#menu` and not its children.

Comment: Anybody notice that he's using `#menu` while the element is `.menu`? Just sayin'.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva i have mentioned it in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  http://jsfiddle.net/WREjV/2/

For all elements in ul

```
$(function(){
    $(".menu li").hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    },function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an ID selector (`#menu`) instead of a class selector (`.menu`).

Change this and it'll work:

```
$(".menu").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    },function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WREjV/4/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/WREjV/1/

You have used `#menu` (refers to ID of an element) selector where you have to use `.menu` as you are providing class, so selector will be `$(".menu")`

```
$(function(){

    $(".menu").hover(function() {
         $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    },function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });


})
```

Comment: @Nrc check my answer once.I created link .it is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Also if you're instructing the LI elements to fadeout on hover there will be nothing left over which to hover in order to trigger a fade in.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I just simplified the case to find the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="first">first</li>
    <li id="second">second</li>
</ul>


$(function(){
        $(".menu li").hover(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        },function() {
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });

        /* This works:
        $("#first").click(function() {
            $("#first").fadeOut("slow");
        });
        */
    })
```

Here `1) "menu" is a class so use want to use '.' not '#' 
      2) You want to do hover for li, so you want to mention the li as well.`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the hash # which is referecne to an ID, so your code is looking for an element with the id "menu".  I have modified the code to use a period (.) which denotes class names

```
$(function(){

    $(".menu").hover(function() {
         $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    },function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });


})
```

See here  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WREjV/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a class in your markup `class="menu">` but you are denoting it with id `$("#menu")` and you should do one change in the markup or in js Either change `class` to `id` or use `.` which denotes the class selector instead of `#` which denotes the ID selector.

#### Either do the change in markup:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="first">first</li>
  <li id="second">second</li>
</ul>
```

#### or in the js:

```
$(".menu").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
},function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to hover all elements. To do that change the selector to include the li's

```
$(function(){
$(".menu li").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");

},function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
})
```